# Default profile photo not being displayed

Tags: django, imagefield

I am working on a twitter clone app and i want users to have a default profile photo when they sign up and login. I have set up the model to upload the default image but for some reason its not displaying.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
#import pylibjpeg_libjpeg
from PIL import Image

# Create your models here.
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', default='default.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    @property
    def followers(self):
        return Follow.objects.filter(follow_user=self.user).count()

    @property
    def following(self):
        return Follow.objects.filter(user=self.user).count()
    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        super().save()
        img = Image.open(self.image.path)
        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

views.py

```
@login_required 
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uform = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        pform = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.profile)

        if uform.is_valid() and pform.is_valid():
            uform.save()
           pform.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Account updated.')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        uform = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        pform = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
    return render(request, 'Users/profile.html', {'uform': uform, 'pform': pform})
```

settings file

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

html file

```
                <article class="media content-section" style="height:140px; width:100%">
                {% if user_profile != None %}
                <div class="mt-2 d-flex full-width align-items-center">
                    <img class="rounded-circle mr-3 img-fluid" style="width:90px; height:90px" src="{{ user_profile.profile.image.url }}">
                    <div>
                        <h4 style="text-align: left" class="white-important">
                            {{ user_profile.username}}
                        </h4>
                        <h6 style="text-align:left" class="email-profile">
                            {{ user.email }}
                        </h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% else %}
                <div class="mt-2 d-flex full-width align-items-center">
                    <img class="rounded-circle mr-3" style="width:90px; height:90px;" src="{{ user.profile.image.url }}" alt="profile picture">
                    <div>
                        <h4 style="text-align: left" class="white-important">
                            {{ user.username }}
                        </h4>
                        <h6 style="text-align:left" class="email-profile">
                            {{ user.email }}
                        </h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {% endif %}
```

my project's urls.py file

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from Users import views as users_views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/',     auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='Users/login.html'),     name='login'),
    path('logout/',     auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='Users/logout.html'),     name='logout'),
    path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='Users/password_reset.html'),name='password-reset'),
    path('password-reset/done', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='Users/password_reset_done.html'), name='password-reset-done'),
    path('password-reset/confirm/<uid64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='Users/password_reset_confirm.html'), name='password-reset-done'),
    path('register/', users_views.register, name='register-users'),
    path('profile/', users_views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('search/', users_views.SearchView, name='search'),
    path('', include("Blog.urls")),
]


if settings.DEBUG is True:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,     document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

here's the screenshot of the output after the user logs in

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are not serving the media files locally. Check the documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

Answer (score 0):

inspect the image on your browser and see what is being rendered. also, try adding a trailing slash to the media_root such that it is `MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')`

Answer (score 0):

In views.py check the **indentation of pform.save()** ...

if still not working follow/check these steps :

**settings.py:**

```
STATIC_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_DIR,
]

#MEDIA
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/' 


LOGIN_URL = 'user_login'
```

create a folder named media with a subfolder profile_pics in your base directory (the folder where you have your manage.py file)

also check this similar code :

**models.py :**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.

class user_profile(models.Model):

    #using default User model by linking 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    #additional fields
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures' , blank = True )
    bio = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import user_profile

class User_form(forms.ModelForm):

    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("username", "email" , "password")

class user_profile_form(forms.ModelForm):
    
    class Meta:
        model = user_profile
        fields = ("profile_picture", "website" , "bio")
```

**views.py :**

```
def signup(request):
    registered = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        
        user_form = User_form(data=request.POST)
        user_profileform = user_profile_form(data=request.POST)

        if(user_form.is_valid() and user_profileform.is_valid()):
            user = user_form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()

            profile = user_profileform.save(commit=False)
            profile.user = user

                    
            if 'profile_picture' in request.FILES:
                profile.profile_picture = request.FILES['profile_picture']
            
            profile.save()

            registered = True
        
        else:
            print(user_form.errors, user_profileform.errors)
    
    else:
        user_form = User_form()
        user_profileform = user_profile_form()

    return render(request, "registration/signup.html", {'user_form': user_form , 'user_profileform' : user_profileform, 'registered' : registered  } )
```

Also make sure your template form has the **"multipart/form-data"**:

**signup.html :**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
                    <div class="container sign-form">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        
                        {{ user_form |as_bootstrap  }}
                        {{ user_profileform |as_bootstrap  }}

                    
                        <!-- {{ user_profileform.as_p }} -->
                        <input type="submit" class = “btn btn-default” name="submit" value="submit">
```

also check if you are rendering the image in the template properly . something like this ,

```
<div class="container">
                <img src="media/{{[context_object_name].image}}" class="imgbar"  id="img">
        </div>
```

even now not solved, open the browser console and let know what is the error displayed

**edit :**

add this[+  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)]  to your urls.py,

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

app_name = 'homepage'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home , name = "home"),
    path('contact', views.contact , name = "contact"),
    path('about', views.about , name = "about"),

] +  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: i have that in my profile.html template, and the indentation is correct. and i have a folder called 'media' in my project directory which has the default.png image that i want to upload

Comment: can you tell me what is the error that shows up in your console !? "Browser Console"

Comment: add     +  static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)        to urls.py .. I have added this as an edit in my answer

Comment: there is no error being displayed. the issue is..the default profile picture is not being displayed automatically when the user registers and logs. meaning i have to login to the database and manually upload the profile photo for the users. I hope this is clear. Also, i have that if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT) in my urls.py

Comment: ok. [ default='default.png'  ] -- so you say this is not working.. right,So set the image field blank = True in your model and in your views.py when there is the POST request during the submission of the form, checkthe request.Files and if there is no file present, then set the image from there. like if no file in request.Files , then Profile.image = " media/{{[context_object_name].image}} "

Comment: Actually its now throwing the Not found '/media/' error on the browser console.

Comment: add this to your urls.py::::: from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings

...
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: it is already there above. ill seperately mention that as edit 2

Comment: i have that in my urls.py file

Comment: from django.conf.urls.static import static this too ?

Comment: as far as i have seen this error occurs when you have some mistakes in the settings.py or adding the import and + media in the urls.py.... please verify the first settings.py lineby line and also the urls.py lines carefully

Comment: yeap. i have added my urls.py file in the edit. It contains that

Comment: also check your file structure carefully. base directory and also the subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

if the images are contained in a subfolder in the "media" directory, e.g. "/media/profile_pics/", then this worked for me (local server) when the user's profile image was not showing up in the profile page:

In the settings.py file, set MEDIA_URL = "/media/profile_pics/"